# Slice content not updated (Android App Action integrated Slice from Google Assistant) Delaying Content

Tags: android, kotlin, actions-on-google, app-actions, android-slices

I create a LoadingSlice first , then after loading the slice content through Rest API, I refresh the slice using "sliceUri".

```
    context.contentResolver.notifyChange(sliceUri, null)
```

My code working fine in App Action Test Tool, but not working through Google assistent. Google Assistent creates the loading Slice correctly, but does not refresh the content of already created Slice after the API call.

**actions.xml**

```
    <?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
    <actions>
                  <action intentName="custom.actions.intent.CHECK_IN" queryPatterns="@array/ExampleInQueries">
             <fulfillment
                 fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
                 urlTemplate="content://com.myapp.v3.slices.provider/checkin">
             </fulfillment>
    
         </action>
    
        </actions>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
    android:name=".slices.MySliceProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.v3.slices.provider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.app.slice.category.SLICE" />
    </intent-filter>

</provider>
```

**MySliceProvider.kt**

```
    class MySliceProvider: SliceProvider()  {
    
        private lateinit var contextNonNull: Context
    
        override fun onCreateSliceProvider(): Boolean {
            contextNonNull = context ?: return false
    
            return true
        }
    
        companion object {
    
            internal const val SLICE_AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.v3.slices.provider"
            var contentLoaded = false
    
        }
    
        private val lastSlices = mutableMapOf<Uri, HCMSlice>()
    
    
        override fun onBindSlice(sliceUri: Uri): Slice {
            return lastSlices.getOrPut(sliceUri) { createNewSlice(sliceUri) }.getSlice()
          
        }
    
        private fun createNewSlice(sliceUri: Uri): HCMSlice {
            loadEnabled = false
    
            when (sliceUri.path) {
                
                DeepLink.CHECKINP -> {
                    return MyCheckSlice(
                        context = contextNonNull,
                        sliceUri = sliceUri
                    )
                }
                        else -> MySlice.Unknown(contextNonNull, sliceUri)
    
                
                
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

**MyCheckSlice.kt**

```
    class MyCheckSlice(
        context: Context,
        sliceUri: Uri
    ) : MySlice(context, sliceUri), KodeinAware{
    override val kodein by kodein(context)
    private val authDataHandler: AuthDataHandler by instance()
    private val authSettings: AuthSettings by instance()
    private val dashboardRepository: DashboardRepository by instance()
    
    override fun getSlice(): Slice {
    
                fetchLeaveTypes()
    
        return if (contentLoaded) {
                createStatsSlice()
    
        } else {
            createLoadingSlice()
        }
    
    }
    
    private fun createStatsSlice(): Slice {
        return list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY) {
            
            row {
                setTitle(context.getString(R.string.slice_success),false)
                setSubtitle("", false)
                primaryAction = createActivityAction()
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    
    private fun createLoadingSlice(): Slice = list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY) {
        row {
              setTitle(context.getString(R.string.slice_processing),true)
              setSubtitle("", true)
    
            primaryAction = createActivityAction()
        }
    }
    
    private fun fetchShift() {
     
        authSettings.checkAuthorizationService(object :
            AuthStateResultListener {
            override fun onStateSuccess() {
    
                Coroutines.main {
                    try {
                        val getCalculateLeaveHoursResponse =  dashboardRepository.getShift(
                            getCurrentDate()!!
                        )
                        getCalculateLeaveHoursResponse.let {
    
                            val jObject = JSONObject(it.data.toString())
                     
                            val jObjShift = jObject.getJSONObject("shift")
                            shiftCode = jObjShift.getInt("shiftCode")
                            contentLoaded = true
                            refresh() 
    
                            return@main
                        }
    
                    } catch (e: ApiException) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftApiException")
                        saveTimeInOut()
                    } catch (e: NoInternetException) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftNoInternetException")
                    } catch (e: HTTPRequestException) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftHTTPRequestException")
                    } catch (e: ApiNocontentException) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftApiNocontentException")
                        saveTimeInOut()
                    }
                }
    
            }
    
            override fun onStateFailure() {
                Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftonStateFailure")
            }
    
            override fun onStateSignout() {
                Log.e("TAG", "fetchShiftonStateSignout")
            }
    
        })
    
    }
    }
```

**MySlice.kt**

```
    abstract class MySlice(val context: Context, val sliceUri: Uri) {
        protected val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        abstract fun getSlice(): Slice
    
        
        protected fun refresh() {
            context.contentResolver.notifyChange(sliceUri, null)
        }
    
        protected fun createActivityAction(): SliceAction {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            return SliceAction.create(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0),
                IconCompat.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                ListBuilder.SMALL_IMAGE,
                context.getString(R.string.slice_enter_app_hint)
            )
        }
    
        class Unknown(context: Context, sliceUri: Uri) : MySlice(context, sliceUri) {
    
            override fun getSlice(): Slice = list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY) {
                
    
                row {
                    
                    title = context.getString(R.string.slice_uri_not_found)
                    
                    primaryAction = createActivityAction()
                }
    
                
                setIsError(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

sample LOG When using App Action Test tool

```
    2021-05-21 18:09:19.780 11102-11120/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onSlicePinned
    2021-05-21 18:09:19.786 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onBindSlice
    2021-05-21 18:09:19.786 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: createNewSlice
    2021-05-21 18:09:19.786 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: content://com.myapp.v3.slices.provider/checkin
    2021-05-21 18:09:20.029 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: contentLoaded=false
    2021-05-21 18:09:20.034 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: createLoadingSlice
    2021-05-21 18:09:29.743 11102-11102/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: fetchShift
    2021-05-21 18:09:29.752 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onBindSlice
    2021-05-21 18:09:29.753 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: contentLoaded=true
    2021-05-21 18:09:29.753 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: createStatsSlice
```

sample LOG When using Google assistant

```
 

    2021-05-21 18:10:26.831 11102-11120/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onSlicePinned
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.833 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onBindSlice
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.833 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: createNewSlice
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.833 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: content://com.myapp.v3.slices.provider/check?name=idcheckin
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.864 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: contentLoaded=false
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.864 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: createLoadingSlice
    2021-05-21 18:10:26.929 11102-11125/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: onSliceUnpinned
    2021-05-21 18:10:27.542 11102-11102/com.myapp.v3 E/TAG: fetchShift
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution has been found yet.